# How to edit reply URL in Azure B2C user flow

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I want to edit the reply URL in my user flow. How can I do this? This is a reset password user-flow. Is this even possible or do I have to create a new user flow from scratch?

[image: Reply URL]

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit it.

But what you can do is have lots of reply URL in the app. and then pick from the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Those URLs are tied to the Application Registrations, each app registration can have multiple return URLs (as you're showing in your screenshot).

If you want to add another URL to that list you need to add it to the app registration for your **LoginAppAndWeb** application. The [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga) explain how to add an app registration, you likely just need to find the existing one for your app and update it.

It's down to the relying party (your actual **LoginAppAndWeb** app) to pass up the correct return URL as part of it's `/authorize` request, B2C will then redirect to that URL at the end of the journey provided it's in the list you've set up in the app registration.

Often, relying parties will have a single return URL so there's a single point B2C redirects to that processes the B2C tokens, then they'll have a separate way of redirecting the user on to another internal URL afterwards. That could be something that's passed as part of the `state` parameter or it could be something that's stored by the browser (e.g. in a cookie), the client library you're using to interact with B2C will likely have a standard way of doing this.